# NextJS: After production if we reload the dynamic url redirecting to homepage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

After uploading to server the dynamic routings are not working after reload of page, its redirecting to Homepage. In local its working fine

Comment: Can you share your redirect config?